# How can I add CSS effects to the 'Scene' of a JavaFX application?

Tags: css, javafx, scene

I need to add a CSS effect to the 'scene' of a certain JavaFX application of mine, not a specific component of the scene or stage. I tried to use:

```
.main-scene{...}
```

and,

```
.main-class{...}
```

But neither worked.

Answer (score 1):

CSS works on nodes not scenes.

There is a css class `.root`, which applies to the root node of all scenes in your application.  For maximum flexibility, the root of the scene should be a [Region](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html) subclass as regions have greater style options in JavaFX.

So for example, if you setup your primary stage like this.

```
Pane pane = new Pane();
pane.setId("my-pane");
stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 300, 200));
```

Then you can style the root pane (of all scenes) using:

```
.root {
   -fx-background-color: yellow;
}
```

Or just the specific root pane in the sample using:

```
#my-pane {
   -fx-background-color: firebrick;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add the desired style to `.root` style class

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm)

> The .root style class is applied to the root node of the Scene
>   instance. Because all nodes in the scene graph are a descendant of the
>   root node, styles in the .root style class can be applied to any node.

The styles written inside this class doesn't need to be applied/added externally. Just add your style within the `.root` and it will be automatically picked up by javafx.

```
.root{
    //Your styles
}
```

*Though you need to externally add the css file !*

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(
  getClass().getResource("myCss.css").toExternalForm()
);
```